# How to reshape Tensor in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, reshape

I have 2 keras tensors: LSTMs and sims. I print out the shapes of the 2 tensors. LSTMs has shape `(1, 18)`, and sims has shape `(18,)`. I want to reshape sims to `(1, 18)`. So I tried with the following code.

```
sims = keras.layers.core.Reshape((1, 18))(sims)
```

keras.layers.core.Reshape gives me the error:

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

I also tried the lambda layer to wrap the tensorflow.reshape().

```
sims = keras.layers.Lambda(reshape, output_shape=(1, 18))(sims)
```

But it gives me a tensor with shape `(18, 1, 18)`

So, my question is how to reshape the sims tensor to the shape `(1, 18)`.

Thanks in advance!

```
    LSTMs = keras.layers.concatenate([lstm1, lstm2, lstm3, lstm4, lstm5, lstm6, lstm7, lstm8, lstm9])


    sims = keras.layers.concatenate([sim1, sim1, sim2, sim2, sim3, sim3, sim4, sim4, sim5,
                                     sim5, sim6, sim6, sim7, sim7, sim8, sim8, sim9, sim9])

    print 'shape(sims)b4', keras.backend.int_shape(sims)
    print 'shape(LSTMs)b4', keras.backend.int_shape(LSTMs)

    sims = keras.layers.core.Reshape((1, 18))(sims)
    #sims = keras.layers.Lambda(reshape, output_shape=(1, 18))(sims)

    print 'shape(sims)af', keras.backend.int_shape(sims)
```

Comment: Do each of the `sim1`, `sim2` and so on, have the same shape?

Comment: @RohitShinde, Yes, they have the same shape

Comment: Well... since you're concatenating 18 sim tensors, there is no way to avoid the output being 18 times what one sim is. Did you intend to `Add()([sim1,sim1,sim2.....])`?? --- If not, you must deal with the fact that the concatenated sims has 18 times the size of one sim. While the concatenated LSTMs has only 9. If you add the results of the print int_shape of every element, we may help more.